# Find and take value of href using protractor

Tags: protractor, href

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CFe7.png)

I had search and read many guides but it doesnot work. Could someone please help me? I want to get the href value like in the image. Thanks for reading my post.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `getAttribute()` method to get the value of any property available in the webelement. In your case you need to find the respective element and can use below code to get the href value,

```
element(by.css("a")).getAttribute("href").then(function(hrefValue){
  console.log("href value",hrefValue);
})
```